# how to send xcode project to client for testing

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios

I'm pretty new here so don't have much idea about it. So sorry for my very simple questions.

I have created simple application in xcode. I want to send that application to client so that he can test it on his device.

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Thank you,
Ankita

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make .ipa file and send it to for testing....You will require developer license.

http://labs.makingwaves.com/2010/09/03/distribute-ad-hoc-iphone-apps-as-ipa-files/

Comment: Yup.  The key phrase you want to remember is "ad hoc distribution".  And you will need to get some information about the particular device it will run on, because this will be needed when you sign your ad hoc application, to prevent it form being run on any other device.

Comment: @Vagrant: To be exact it will require the Device ID of device on which we need to test

Comment: @iSwamp: I read the URL you have given but it doesn't say i require developer license. Can you please tell me where do i require that?

Comment: You need a subscription to Apple's iOS developer program before you can run the app on any device, even your own.

Comment: Do I only need? Or my client also needs it?

Comment: @Ankita Chordia:  You can add upto 100 devices for testing into your developer account. It means you can test 100 apps if you consider one device per client

Comment: @Ankita Chordia: Subscription to Apple iOS developer program is only required by one party i.e. either you or your client. It is not required that both should have that subscription. But finally if the client wants that the app should be launched in app-store under his name then he needs to have a subscription which has his name.

Answer (score 2):

[TestFlight](http://testflightapp.com) is a service which makes managing ad-hoc deployment and testing much easier than doing it manually.

Comment: I was just going to post the same thing, also wanted to mention he should use "Build and Archive" and then use the Organizer to generate the IPA file.

Comment: Once you have worked out how to do an adhoc build, testflight doesn't add much. If you have a web server you can put a .ipa on and can edit two text files I'm not sure what it adds. Best of all - http://bit.ly/hE7uBm - automatically build and publish adhoc builds for OTA distribution as soon as you commit!

Comment: TestFlight allows you to add new testers on-the-fly without rebuilding, alerts testers to new builds, tracks who has the build installed, etc.  Agreed, nothing you can't do manually, but it does roll it up into a very nice package.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AdHoc version of your app.

You just need to code sign with your distribution profile.

Also you need to add a entitlements.plist which contains item called "get-task-allow"  with type as Boolean and value as NO.

Now you simply need to add this Entitlements.plist to your code signing entitlements and then you need to just "Clean" and "Build and Archive".

The archive would be formed in Oragnizer. Then you need to share it as save it to disk as `<appname>.<versionnumber>.ipa`

Now this .ipa file along with your .mobileprovsion file is to be sent to your client.

**NOTE:**

You need to add the client's Device ID to your distribution profile. Only then the Client's device would be allowed to install this app on it and test it.

Hope this helps you.

If you have any doubts on this then you may just leave a comment here. :-)